# Why is gunicorn spawning 3 times the number of workers I requested?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, process, gunicorn

I have the following docker compose command:

`command: gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:9000 myapp.wsgi:server`

Upon running `docker compose up`, my server is very slow! So I run `ps -auxf` to investigate and I see:

```
/usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace moby -id e890c3d533cd8c51fbc1e8de2498f3de667f557ba3aead1632d59cde17dfc19e -address /run/containerd
 \_ /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:9000 myapp.wsgi:server
     \_ /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:9000 myapp.wsgi:server
     |   \_ /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:9000 myapp.wsgi:server
     |   \_ /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:9000 myapp.wsgi:server
     |   \_ /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:9000 myapp.wsgi:server
     \_ /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:9000 myapp.wsgi:server
     |   \_ /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:9000 myapp.wsgi:server
     |   \_ /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:9000 myapp.wsgi:server
     |   \_ /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:9000 myapp.wsgi:server
     \_ /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:9000 myapp.wsgi:server
         \_ /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:9000 myapp.wsgi:server
         \_ /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:9000 myapp.wsgi:server
         \_ /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:9000 myapp.wsgi:server
```

It seems like docker or gunicorn is spawning **3x** the number of server processes, contrary to the 3 I was expecting.

What am I missing here? Is this a docker configuration issue on my part? or a gunicorn configuration issue?

Comment: I am also facing similar issue, but not using docker. I am just starting gunicorn using systemd, it is spawning 3 workers, though I am specifying 1. Did you managed to solve it?

Comment: I switched the # of workers to # of threads.